# Do Not Disturb in plist file

Tags: ios6, settings, plist, toggle, jailbreak

I want to program a SBSettings toggle for the Do Not Disturb Feature in iOS 6, but I can't find the plist file, where it Is saved. Can please somebody help me?

PS: Is there a possibility to Check which file has changed after doing something? Like a Log file. Because I think it's very boring to look for each savepoint I wanna search for..

Comment: Try first using a simple find command, to check for plist files modified in the last 5 minutes: `find / -name '*.plist' -mmin -5`.  Or change 5 to something smaller.  Obviously, you need to toggle the setting first.  That won't tell you which one it is, but it will narrow the list of choices.  Use `plutil` then to display the contents of plists that were modified, searching for something that looks like Do Not Disturb.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the function I was looking for! But when I want to use plutil, the Terminal says, there Is no function named so.

Comment: If you go into Cydia, lookup the package named **Erica Utilities**.  I believe it installs `plutil`, as well as lots of other great utilities.

Comment: ok thank you, but I like using file more.
I've checked the changes now many times, but there is no change! how is this possible?

Comment: @Will, this question relates to jailbroken applications, whether as the other is answered in the context of official APIs. So the others's answer is not relevant to this question. I am interested in both and would like to have seen if any answers trickle through as time goes by.